# Math:CDF perl library - Installation issue

Tags: linux, perl, module, path

I would like to use a Toolbox, which relies on Perl library Math::CDF:
https://metacpan.org/source/CALLAHAN/Math-CDF-0.1/README

I don't have root permission on the cluster, so I installed Math-CDF-0.1 locally. It seemed that installation was successful, and I could run some analysis using this module yesterday. Today, when I re-open Terminal, the Toolbox has issues when calling the module. I am new to Perl and cannot figure out where the problem is and how what I am doing today is different from yesterday.

To install Math:CDF:

```
perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=path/Math-CDF-0.1
make
make install
```

As a result, I got:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `path/Math-CDF-0.1/cdflib'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `path/Math-CDF-0.1/cdflib'
Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
Installing path/Math-CDF-0.1/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Math/CDF/CDF.bs
Installing path/Math-CDF-0.1/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Math/CDF/CDF.so
Installing path/Math-CDF-0.1/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Math/CDF/autosplit.ix
Installing /path/Math-CDF-0.1/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Math/CDF.pm
Installing path/Math-CDF-0.1/man/man3/Math::CDF.3pm
Appending installation info to path/Math-CDF-0.1/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/perllocal.pod
```

I added paths to @INC (path/ctk and path/czplib are where the Toolbox scripts are):

```
  @INC:
    path/ctk
    path/Math-CDF-0.1
    path/czplib
    /usr/local/lib64/perl5
    /usr/local/share/perl5
    /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib64/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
```

Now, when I run the actual script, I get the following error:

```
perl path/ctk/fastq_filter.pl -v -f mean:0-24:20 -of fasta BrainA_130_50_fastq.txt BrainA_new.fa
Can't locate Math/CDF.pm in @INC (@INC contains: path/ctk path/Math-CDF-0.1 path/czplib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at path/czplib/Common.pm line 924.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at path/czplib/Common.pm line 924.
Compilation failed in require at /path/ctk/fastq_filter.pl line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at path/ctk/fastq_filter.pl line 10.
```

`CDF.pm` is in `path/Math-CDF-0.1` which is in @INC.

Could you please help me to understand what is wrong?

EDITS:
Testing `perl -mMath::CDF -e 1` does show that there is an issue (thank you toolic!)

```
Can't locate loadable object for module Math::CDF in @INC (@INC contains: path/ctk pathMath-CDF-0.1 path/czplib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at -e line 0 Compilation failed in require. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

Comment: This helped, thank you! But now I get another error message: ```Can't locate loadable object for module Math::CDF in @INC (@INC contains: path/Math-CDF-0.1 path/czplib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at path/czplib/Common.pm line 924```

Comment: I saw somewhere online that one can check perl -e Math:CDF and if it returns nothing, then it is good sign. Testing ```perl -mMath::CDF -e 1``` does show that there is an issue (Thank you for catching this up!) ```Can't locate loadable object for module Math::CDF in @INC (@INC contains: path/ctk pathMath-CDF-0.1 path/czplib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at -e line 0
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.```

Comment: I tried to install `Math::CDF` with perlbrew and `perl` version 5.30. After `cpanm Math::CDF` the module files ended up in `/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/lib/site_perl/5.30.0/x86_64-linux/Math/CDF.pm` and `/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/lib/site_perl/5.30.0/x86_64-linux/auto/Math/CDF/CDF.so` and it is enough that `/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/lib/site_perl/5.30.0/x86_64-linux` is in `@INC` for the module to be loadable

Comment: Seems like you are missing path `path/Math-CDF-0.1/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi` in your `@INC` ?

Comment: Adding ```path/Math-CDF-0.1/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi``` to my ```@INC``` solved the problem! Thank you very much Håkon Hægland!